# ProgressBar disappeared in Android

Tags: android

I have a somewhat big app with a bunch of progressBars (just regular indeterminate progress spinning wheels, no special styling) distributed througout the whole app.

Today I was developing some other stuff and realised the progress bars dont show anymore!!

I reverted to a previous version and the progress bar weren't there either! This version I have on the play Store and it does have the progress bar, so this is really weird.

The only thing I changed that I can think of is updating gradle plugin (and I cannot revert that now), could this be related somehow?

Comment: Do you use any testing library?

Comment: yes, I use espresso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably disabled the animations since espresso instructs to do so.
https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/index.html

> Setup your test environment
>
> To avoid flakiness, we highly recommend that you turn off system animations on the virtual or physical device(s) used for testing.
>
> On your device, under Settings->Developer options disable the following 3 settings:
> Window animation scale
> Transition animation scale
> Animator duration scale

Enable those again if you are not testing.

Comment: @MichelReap If this answers your question, accept it please. Thanks!